# Avoid dnf update modification of /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

Yesterday I ran dnf update, which updated various php packages.

I discovered some values that I had customized in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf were reset after the update.

Specifically, I had these 3 values set to custom directories owned by Nginx:

```
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/nginx/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/nginx/wsdlcache
php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /var/nginx/opcache
```

But after update, these values reverted to the default ones.

Is there a better way to configure this so that these values don't overwritten every time the php packages are upgraded?

Comment: Where did you get php-fpm from? This file should be marked as a config file in the RPM and not be overwritten if you've customized it.

Comment: I know, that's why I was so surprised to see the config overwritten. Here is the source according to dnf info: ```php-7.3.5-5.module_el8.2.0+314+53b99e08.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : AppStream```